# Synchronize Togglebuttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Press any togglebutton in Menu all other togglebuttons will be unchecked.

I found one solution that suits me, and I'm very sorry to everyone who will see it.

Menu
[image]

[Xaml]

```
            <WrapPanel x:Name="ToggleButtons">
                <ToggleButton x:Name="Products" Checked="TopMenuButton_Checked">
                    <ToggleButton.OpacityMask>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/product-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    </ToggleButton.OpacityMask>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="Incoming_products" Checked="TopMenuButton_Checked">
                    <ToggleButton.OpacityMask>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/document-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    </ToggleButton.OpacityMask>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="Storehouses" Checked="TopMenuButton_Checked">
                    <ToggleButton.OpacityMask>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/warehouse-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    </ToggleButton.OpacityMask>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="Products_in_storehouse" Checked="TopMenuButton_Checked">
                    <ToggleButton.OpacityMask>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/store-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                    </ToggleButton.OpacityMask>
                </ToggleButton>
            </WrapPanel>
```

[C#]

```
private void TopMenuButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(ToggleButton b in ToggleButtons.Children)
            {
                if (b != (ToggleButton)sender)
                {
                    b.IsChecked = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

If you have any other solution, please, let me know.

Comment: Welcome on SO. What is your exact problem?

Comment: You might want to post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you just want comments on working code.

Comment: Looks like you want to re-invent the RadioButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wpf controls are lookless.

Assuming you're OK with one of these always being pressed once one is you could instead use radiobuttons. They encapsulate the behaviour you seem to desire.

Re template them to whatever you like. I've just thrown a button in here with a templatebinding but you could use togglebutton, rectangle or whatever.

```
    <WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value='True'/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                            <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </WrapPanel.Resources>
        <RadioButton/>
        <RadioButton/>
        <RadioButton/>
```

I'm not sure this is much more elegant than what you have at the moment but maybe it's interesting anyhow.

Maybe some more inspiration. You can template a radiobutton as a path. These are buttons in the article but they could be any control. A datagrid would be very strange but you could re template one into a path.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29866.aspx

There are other options you could consider.

A listbox has a selecteditem which you could work with.

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OptionList}"
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>.
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             Each icon templated here
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Then the selected item can drive whatever clicking on your togglebuttons does.

You can bind it or use an eventhandler and code.

Another option is a tabcontrol.

Template the header.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally checked [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75171255/21042547)'s solution and it works just fine for me!
What I did was this:
I created a custom template for RadioButton:

```
<Style x:Key="ImageIcon" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="70"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="70"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        CornerRadius="15"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Opacity="0.4">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                          Focusable="False"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.7"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.4"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Shortly, dis code just transform RadioButton to regular Button, which will have it's content half transparent if not selected (Btw, the borders are with corner radius :)). Delete the Width and Height part in Triggers, you probably won't need it.

Than I created an ItemControl inside a ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="0,0,0,10">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton x:Name="Image" Style="{DynamicResource ImageIcon}" GroupName="Images" Checked="Image_Checked">
                    <RadioButton.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Data, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    </RadioButton.Background>
                </RadioButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I still have a bad code behind it, but the original problem is solved!

So, right now, it does someth like this:
[When I click RadioButton, it changes the main image's source to button's content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FusQ3.jpg)